# Determine cell value to find in another sheet the same value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with all the store locations and an email template. In the email template sheet a vlookup result will show in G25.I need the value in G25 (e.g. New Barrie) to find in another sheet (All Locations) the same value "New Barrie".

I don't know how to look for the value in G25 instead of the hardcoded  New Barrie.

```
Sub Email()

' Email Macro

Range("G25").Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("All Locations").Select

Cells.Find(What:="New Barrie", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _

    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _

    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Range("A37").Select

Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

Sheets("Email Template").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're after something like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Email()
    Dim val As String
    Dim myCell As Range

    val = Worksheets("template").Range("G25").Value '<--| store worksheet "template" cell "G25" value into a string variable
    Set myCell = Worksheets("All Locations").Cells.Find(What:=val, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) '<--| set myCell to the one in "All Locations" worksheet whose content matches the stored value

    If Not myCell Is Nothing Then myCell.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

just review `LookIn`, `LookAt` and `MatchCase` arguments of `Find()` method to be sure they actually fits your need

Comment: @Jira, did you get through it?